# ggplot presentation of attribute column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two set of time series data. I would like to plot them with respect to the time and date. Moreover, they are number of attributes (-1 or 1) for the corresponding time under the title of outlier and they should be presented with a symbol where outlier="-1" on the plot. Moreover, another problem in my code is in the Legend the title of the legend and one of the contents of the legend appeared similarly.

```
true   pred   outlier   dtt 
0.05       0    1   9/29/2007 0:00  
-0.33      0    1   9/29/2007 1:00  
-0.41      0    1   9/29/2007 2:00  
-0.69      0    1   9/29/2007 3:00  
-0.68      0    1   9/29/2007 4:00  
-0.43   -0.53   1   9/29/2007 5:00  
-0.12   -0.23   1   9/29/2007 6:00  
0.15    0.16    1   9/29/2007 7:00  
0.56    0.39    1   9/29/2007 8:00  
0.98    0.87    1   9/29/2007 9:00  
1.18    1.27    1   9/29/2007 10:00 
2.14    1.31    1   9/29/2007 11:00 
4.12    2.87    1   9/29/2007 12:00 
5.59    5.43    1   9/29/2007 13:00 
6.90    6.52    1   9/29/2007 14:00 
6.40    7.80    1   9/29/2007 15:00 
5.88    5.78    1   9/29/2007 16:00 
6.14    5.58    1   9/29/2007 17:00 
4.61    6.20    -1  9/29/2007 18:00 
5.15    6.20    1   9/29/2007 19:00 
2.74    4.54    -1  9/29/2007 20:00 
4.66    4.54    1   9/29/2007 21:00 
5.10    4.74    1   9/29/2007 22:00 
4.79    5.53    1   9/29/2007 23:00
```

Applied code:

```
ggplot(second_data_results_node25, aes( second_data_results_node25$dtt)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = second_data_results_node25$true, colour = "TRUE")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = second_data_results_node25$pred, colour = "Prediction"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to draw using `ggplot2`, you'll have to shape your data accordingly. Since you have two variables, you could `melt` them (I use `reshape2` here to melt) and use `group` in `ggplot2` as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df <- structure(list(true = c(0.05, -0.33, -0.41, -0.69, -0.68, -0.43, 
-0.12, 0.15, 0.56, 0.98, 1.18, 2.14, 4.12, 5.59, 6.9, 6.4, 5.88, 
6.14, 4.61, 5.15, 2.74, 4.66, 5.1, 4.79), pred = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -0.53, -0.23, 0.16, 0.39, 0.87, 1.27, 1.31, 2.87, 5.43, 6.52, 
7.8, 5.78, 5.58, 6.2, 6.2, 4.54, 4.54, 4.74, 5.53), outlier = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), dtt = c("9/29/2007 0:00", "9/29/2007 1:00", 
"9/29/2007 2:00", "9/29/2007 3:00", "9/29/2007 4:00", "9/29/2007 5:00", 
"9/29/2007 6:00", "9/29/2007 7:00", "9/29/2007 8:00", "9/29/2007 9:00", 
"9/29/2007 10:00", "9/29/2007 11:00", "9/29/2007 12:00", "9/29/2007 13:00", 
"9/29/2007 14:00", "9/29/2007 15:00", "9/29/2007 16:00", "9/29/2007 17:00", 
"9/29/2007 18:00", "9/29/2007 19:00", "9/29/2007 20:00", "9/29/2007 21:00", 
"9/29/2007 22:00", "9/29/2007 23:00")), .Names = c("true", "pred", 
"outlier", "dtt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L
))

df.m <- melt(df, names(df)[3:4], names(df)[1:2])
df.m$outlier <- factor(df.m$outlier)
df.m$dtt <- strptime(as.character(df.m$dtt), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
p <- ggplot(df.m, aes(x = dtt, y = value, group = variable, color = variable))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(shape = outlier))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
p
```

[image: Result_ggplot2]

Comment: There is a problem with dtt variable in this plot. Time is in wrong order (10:00 after 1:00). You could use strptime() function to convert it to datetime format and then use scale_x_datetime() for more flexibility.

Comment: would u plz explore, what didi u mean by select=-c(X)?

Comment: In the new code, I came up with following error:  df.m$dtt <- strptime(as.character(df.m$dtt), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dtt", value = list(sec = numeric(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 48

Comment: It gives: > nrow(df.m)
[1] 48

Comment: Yes, the problem is here. my table include other columns as : true, pred,       resid,       u,l        ll, outlier, event, ltp, lfp, ldr,     lfpr and dtt. Should I modify the table to have pred , true and dtt column successive?

Comment: The plot doesn't appear even by the code u put it in the answer part. There is no error but plot doesn't appeared.